# What is the sunnah way to a morning routine?

Tags: salat, sunnah

I see a lot of very productive people and multi-millionaires with a regular early morning routine. As the Prophet Muhammad SAWS is supposed to be the best example, what morning routine did the Prophet and his companions follow?

Answer (score 3):

Sleep early, wake up during the last third of the night. Recite the Qur'an during this period.

> In my house he (Prophet (p.b.u.h) ) never passed the last hours of the night but sleeping. (Bukhari 234)
>
> "Perform the Salat (Prayer) from midday till the darkness of the night, and recite the Qur'an in the early dawn. Verily, the recitation of the Qur'an in the early dawn is ever witnessed (attended by the angels)." (Al-'Isra' 17:78)

Brush your teeth before the night prayers.

> Whenever the Prophet got up for Tahajjud prayer he used to clean his mouth (and teeth) with Siwak. (Bukhari 237)

Do 7-11 rak'at of Tahajjud and Witr prayer. One can optionally do other prayers before this as well, such as Istikharah.

> I asked Aisha about the night prayer of Allah's Apostle and she said, "It was seven, nine or eleven Rakat besides the two Rakat of the Fajr prayer (i.e. Sunna). " (Bukhari 240)
>
> The Prophet (p.b.u.h) used to offer thirteen Rakat of the night prayer and that included the Witr and two Rakat (Sunna) of the Fajr prayer.

Pray 2 rakaat before the Fajr prayer. Recite just brief surahs during this prayer.

> The two rak'ahs at dawn are better than this world and what it contains. (Muslim 118)
>
> The Prophet (p.b.u.h) used to make the two Rakat before the Fajr prayer so light that I would wonder whether he recited Al-Fatiha (or not). (Bukhari 262)

Do the Ishraaq prayer about 12 minutes after sunrise.

> Abu Hurairah has also related that the eternally blessed Prophet once sent some companions on jihad. They returned soon with much booty. Someone asked in surprise how the military expedition returned so soon with so much booty. The Holy Prophet said, "Should I not tell you about the men who would come back even sooner and still more booty?" Then he said, "He who performs his ablution well, then completes his fajr prayer and then (after sunrise) performs his Ishraq prayer, comes sooner and with greater booty" (Targhib p. 427. vol. I ref. Abu Yate ba Isnad-e-Sahib).

Bathe in the morning. Put on some deodorant.

> 'Aisha said, "May Allah be Merciful to Abu 'Abdur-Rahman. I used to put scent on Allah's Apostle and he used to go round his wives, and in the morning he assumed the Ihram, and the fragrance of scent was still coming out from his body." (Bukhari 267)

Answer (score 0):

You might be asking the routine of Prophet Muhammad(peace be upon him) from the time he woke up in morning.
I feel better to start from the time he first wakes up for Tahajjud prayer.

As soon as he used to woke up, he used to recite surah Qaf, then attend his nature calls,
then pray Tahajjud Salah(a few rakat), then used to take a nap until adhan of Fajr is said.

Then after that he used to pray 2 rakah salah and then used to lead the Fajr prayer, and then after complete sunrise used to pray Ishraq salah.

And then the people used to disperse for work.

And also Qur'an says something...

> ...Indeed, the recitation of dawn is ever witnessed (Qur'an 17:78)

May the creator guide us all.